# No component being rendered on router.push('/page') unless reloaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-router

On successful login, I'm embedding the user token in browser cookies and using `router.push('/dashboard')` to take the user to his dashboard, but the '/dashboard' page is not rendering any components unless I trigger a reload, on which all the components are rendered on the screen.

Code block from `/login` page:

```js
const Auth = () => {
  const [
    verifyOTPMutation,
    { data: verifyOTPRes, loading, error: verifyOtpError },
  ] = useMutation(VerifyOTP, {
    variables: {
      mobileNumber: phoneInput,
      mobileCountryCode: countryCodeInput,
      otp: otpInput,
    },
  }
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!verifyOTPRes) {
    return;
  }

  if (verifyOTPRes) {
    setCookies(
      "token",
      verifyOTPRes.accessToken,
      { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, }
    );
  }

  router.replace(`/dashboard`);
}, [verifyOTPRes]);

return (
<>
  <h6>Enter OTP</h6>

  <input
    onChange={e => {
      setOTPInput(parseInt((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
    }}
  ></input>

  <button onClick={() => verifyOTPMutation()}>
    Verify OTP
  </button>
  </>
)}
```

Code block from `/dashboard` page:

```
const Courses = () => {
  return <h1>My Dashboard</h1>;
};
```

which on first returns a blank white page and on if reloaded, returns:

```html
<h1>My Dashboard</h1>
```

Comment: did you open your console in browser and see if it throws an error when the push happens?

Comment: Also is really hard to debug your code like this. Maybe try to reproduce your issue in a sandbox

Comment: Hey @bill.gates there aren't any errors thrown in the browser console.

Comment: @Berci not able to reproduce the same in a sandbox. It seems to be working fine there.

Comment: if any error logs just copy your console error text.

Comment: Hey @VitoMohagheghian there aren't any errors thrown in the browser console.

Comment: Do you have a _app.js set up? If you do, share that as well, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had to trigger an update, I went ahead with using window.location.href('/dashboard') which worked. Thanks, @Abhinay.

Comment: Hi, you should accept the answer that pointed you to the right solution

Comment: Hey @pierpy I've already done so.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `route.replace()` which is responsible for replacing the url without reloading the page.

```
the replace() method can be used to update the URL displayed in the address bar without reloading the page:
```

Refer: https://iq.js.org/questions/react/what-is-the-purpose-of-push-and-replace-methods-of-history

try using `router.push()` instead.

Comment: router.push doesn't refresh the page either. They work the same. It's just that replace doesn't add the login page to the queue  (so when you push the back arrow the user won't go to the login page again)